# How to check/Monitor Redis Activity

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, redis-cluster

I set up a Redis cluster on Google Cloud Platform as a cache service for my app running on Kubernetes Engine. I have before been having warnings about failure to connect to Redis but after redeploying I get no more issues.

[image: Previous Issue]

However, how can I be sure that my Redis is now serving well and can see its activity like on a command line in case a make a request to the application? Is there a way & commands I can run on `redis-cli` to see its activity?

Comment: Your redis is located in your GKE Cluster or in memory store service ?
If in GKE use `kubectl proxy` to reach service

Comment: Did you deploy the redis cluster into Kubernetes? Please try to describe better you scenario.